# SSD causing issues with computer freezing

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, freeze, dell-xps

I have a Dell XPS 15 L521X. The computer will freeze when booting or starting up. I have opened up the laptop and found the issue, my SSD. When the SSD is out and unplugged from the laptop, the laptop will start up fine (obviously won't boot, though). However, when the SSD is plugged in, the computer will turn on and if you apply any pressure on the SSD it will freeze the whole computer. Note that the computer will only turn on with the SSD in without the back cover of the laptop on, I assume that's because the back cover applies pressure on the SSD. What is wrong with my SSD, is it fixable or will I need a new one?

Comment: do you use the SSD in a hdd caddy in DVD/BD slot?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Not sure what you mean by this. It is held in place by a bracket onto the motherboard of my computer. It just connects to a plug on the motherboard.

Comment: [this is a caddy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEzrB.jpg) if this doesn't apply to you you have a different issue. when using this adapter, you should put the HDD in it in the SSD to the native slot in the laptop.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I use the big plug that is next to the caddy in that picture to plug the SSD into the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if the SSD is shorting something out when there is pressure on it.  From my experiences that is BAD.  I'd take it back to wherever you got it and see if they'll fix it, that should not happen at all.  If you want to do it yourself, knowing what type of drive it is will help you make your purchase.  I would get a new SSD, copy the data over and then think about what to do with the old SSD.  The Dell you listed has two possible storage locations from what I read on their site, so I'm not sure which one you're talking about, but I'm mostly sure it's the mSATA that you're having issues with.  More details about the SSD are needed though.

EDIT: Before I forget, backup your data before doing anything.  There's a chance you might loose stuff because of a bad SSD, there's an even better chance of you loosing things from mediocre computer techs just swapping out your drives and not caring about your data at all.